# Draw a colored sphere from cartesian coordinates in pymol

Tags: python, visualization, bioinformatics

I was looking in the wiki how to convert the following information about beads, cartesian coordinates + energy :

23.4 54.6 12.3 -123.5 54.5 23.1 9.45 -56.7 .......

to a draw in pymol that contains for each atom a sphere of radius R, centered on its coordinates, and with color, in a rainbow gradient.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Does what you're rendering actually have anything to do with molecular structure (i.e. what is the motivation for using PyMol)?

If you are drawing some molecular structure, I would recommend just outputting a custom PDB file with the sphere coordinates (you can use the B-factor field per ATOM line as a way of controlling per-atom coloring in PyMol).

If you are not drawing a molecular structure, you would be best off using the CGO interface of PyMol.

From the PyMol documentation:

> CGO spheres are generated by the
>   SPHERE command.
>
> SPHERE, x,y,z,d
>
> where x,y,z are the coordinates of the
>   sphere centre and d is the diameter of
>   the sphere. Note how a COLOR command
>   is used to set the colour of a sphere.
>   As with LINES you only need a COLOR
>   command when the colour of the next
>   sphere to be drawn changes.

A simple example:

```
from pymol.cgo import *
from pymol import cmd

spherelist = [
   COLOR,    0.100,    1.000,    0.000,
   SPHERE,   30.304,   30.407,   30.531,0.30,
   COLOR,    1.000,    0.000,    0.000,
   SPHERE,   30.250,   30.250,   30.250,0.20,
    ]

cmd.load_cgo(spherelist, 'segment',   1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting the rainbow gradient bit, but concerning the code above/below I had to change it as :

```
import pymol

from pymol.cgo import *

from pymol import (
                    
                    cmd ,
                    )


print('########## PYMOL VERSION ##########################################')
print('         ',  cmd.get_version() )
print('###################################################################')


pymol.finish_launching()

spherelist = [
   [COLOR,    0.100,    1.000,    0.000,
   SPHERE,   30.304,   30.407,   30.531,0.30],
   [COLOR,    1.000,    0.000,    0.000,
   SPHERE,   30.250,   30.250,   30.250,0.20],
    ]

for i in spherelist:
    
    a = str(spherelist.index(i))

    cmd.load_cgo(i, 'sphere_'+a )
```

in Pymol version as per output:

```
########## PYMOL VERSION ##########################################
          ('2.3.0',
```

to have singles objects like `spheres_0` and `spheres_1` objects looking like :

[image] .

Had to look into code to figure out the third argument in `load_cgo` missing from the wiki : [Load CGO PyMOLWiki](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Load_CGO) , but maybe the `zoom` can be passed along in a lot of commands I guess:

`cmd.load_cgo(obj , cgo_name , zoom=0)`